# Invalid type: expected type is BindableProperty

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set the Padding based on the platform with the following code

```xml
<ContentView.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="iOS">16,24,16,4</On>
        <On Platform="Windows">16,16,16,4</On>
        <On Platform="Android">16,16,16,4</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentView.Padding>
```

However, I'm getting a red squiggly on `OnPlatform` with the following error

```
Invalid type: expected type is BindableProperty, actual type is OnPlatform<Thickness>
```

What's the correct way to configure this?

Comment: This is the one of the right ways to configure this. I don't see anything wrong with this code snippet. Could it be one of those 'false positive' intellisense errors?

Comment: You get the red squiggles, but does it works ? It should.

Comment: Yes you both are right! It's one of those false positives

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on mine, also running 2.3.4. If it doesn't work on yours you will need to show more code, perhaps doing something weird in the code behind.

```
    <ContentView.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="16,24,16,4"></On>
        <On Platform="Windows" Value="16,16,16,4"></On>
        <On Platform="Android" Value="16,16,16,4"></On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentView.Padding>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<ContentView>
    <ContentView.Padding>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" 
                  Android="16,16,16,4" 
                  WinPhone="16,16,16,4"
                  iOS="16,24,16,4"/>
   </ContentView.Padding>
 <ContentView>`
```

This worked for me